# Where can I find a list of COM libraries with no .NET equivalent?

Tags: .net, com, comparison

Does a list exist that compares and contrasts Windows' COM components with their .NET equivalents, e.g.

ADSI <-> System.Directory

WMI <-> System.Management

etc.?

I am especially interested in a list of COM components that have no .NET equivalent. My Google-Fu failed me badly on this one...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most COM objects do not have .Net equivalent because they are not written by Microsoft. However you can use .Net's COM support to call them.

It is not Microsoft's best interest to make unnecessary promises on implementation details, otherwise people would rely on it and make changing implementation harder. For example, Microsoft can not remove the shell folder registry entries designed to support 4 programs written for Windows 95 Beta 3 to continue running on Windows 95, even when they want them out since Windows 95 RTM.

here is an [old map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302340.aspx) designed to make moving SDK to .Net easier.